# Generate correlated random variables with a specific structure

Tags: probability, correlation, random-variable, matlab, cross-correlation

Three random variables, $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$, are complex Gaussian with a correlation matrix $\Sigma$. Additionally, three random variables, $Y_1$, $Y_2$, and $Y_3$, are also complex Gaussian with a correlation matrix $\Sigma$. Furthermore, the correlation between $(X_1, Y_1)$, $(X_2, Y_2)$, and $(X_3, Y_3)$ is $\rho$. I attempted to implement this in MATLAB as follows:

```
L=3;
N=10^6;
mu = zeros(L,1); 
sigma = [1.0000, 0.1150, 0.8736; 0.1150, 1.0000, 0.1641; 0.8736, 0.1641, 1.0000]
R = mvnrnd(mu, sigma, N);  
I = mvnrnd(mu, sigma, N);  
X = R + 1i * I;  
rho = 0.15;
Z = randn(N, L) + 1i * randn(N, L);
Y = rho * X + sqrt(1 - rho^2) * Z;
correlation_matrix_X = real(corrcoef(X))
correlation_matrix_XY = real(corrcoef(X(:,1),Y(:,1)))
correlation_matrix_Y = real(corrcoef(Y))
```

However, I discovered that it does not work as the output of `correlation_matrix_Y` was:

```
sigma =

    1.0000    0.1150    0.8736
    0.1150    1.0000    0.1641
    0.8736    0.1641    1.0000


correlation_matrix_X =

    1.0000    0.1149    0.8740
    0.1149    1.0000    0.1640
    0.8740    0.1640    1.0000


correlation_matrix_XY =

    1.0000    0.1506
    0.1506    1.0000


correlation_matrix_Y =

    1.0000    0.0018    0.0203
    0.0018    1.0000    0.0033
    0.0203    0.0033    1.0000
```

I have doubts about whether it is possible to generate random variables with this specific correlation structure.

Could you please confirm if it is indeed possible?

If it is, could you please assist me in generating them?